# Entity forms problems with Symfony2 relation many to many

Tags: forms, many-to-many, entity, symfony

I’m actually learning Symfony2 and I have a problem. I have a relation many to many between a movie and an actor.

I have created a form to create a new movie. In this form I have a selected input to choose actors but when I select many actors the form generated an error “This value should not be blank”. When I delete my assert in actor class I haven’t this error.
Why my form check the assert in my actor class?

```
    /*
       *  MOVIE CLASS
       *
       */    
    class Movie
        {
            //...


            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Actor", inversedBy="movies")
             * @ORM\JoinTable(name="movie_actor")
             */
            protected $actors;
        }

       /*
       *  ACTOR CLASS
       *
       */

        class Actor
        {

            /**
             * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
             * @Assert\NotBlank()
             * @Assert\MinLength(3)
             */
            protected $firstName;

            /**
             * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
             * @Assert\NotBlank()
             * @Assert\MinLength(3)
             */
            protected $lastName;

            /**
             * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable = true)
             */
            protected $birthday;

            /**
             * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
             * @Assert\NotBlank()
             */
            protected $sexe;


            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Movie", mappedBy="actors")
             * @Assert\NotNull()
             */
            protected $movies;
        }


/**
*
* MOVIE FORM 
*/
class MovieType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('category')
            ->add('actors', 'entity',  
            array(
                'class' => 'MyAppFilmothequeBundle:Actor',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
                    {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')->orderBy('a.firstName', 'ASC');
                    },
                 'multiple' => true
            ))
            ->add('user')
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
        'data_class' => 'MyApp\FilmothequeBundle\Entity\Movie');
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'movie';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation is done by adding a set of rules (called constraints) to a class. So your form looks at assertions you put in the related class to check if submitted data is valid or not. Check the [Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation) chapter.

One more thing: entity field as a ["required" option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#required) set to "true" by default. Just set it to false, if you really want it.

Comment: And as the official documentation also says, required is only used for client side validation via HTML5 attribute required.